# How do I get a VSCode Remote - Containers devcontainer to use a forwarded SSH Agent for Git credentials?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh

In Microsoft's [docs on sharing git credentials with a devcontainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_using-ssh-keys) they state:

> the extension will automatically forward your local SSH agent if one is running

However:

#### Locally:

I'm in OSX (Big Sur) and have an ssh agent running.

`ssh-add -l` gives:

```
256 SHA256:somelongkeyblahblah me@myemail.com (ED25519)
```

`cat ~/.ssh/config` gives:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

#### In the remote container:

`echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` gives:

```
/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-0fa193ba528678ff6157458207dbd1facaa44958.sock
```

`ssh-add -l` gives:

```
The agent has no identities.
```

`cat ~/.ssh/config` gives:

```
/bin/cat: /root/.ssh/config: No such file or directory
```

and `ls -al ~/.ssh` gives:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 20 10:29 .
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Jul 20 10:29 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  799 Jul 20 10:29 known_hosts
```

#### Question

Clearly, my ssh agent isn't being "automatically forwarded". I'm not very experienced in this area - what's my next move? How do I determine if this is due to something I've done, or due to a bug in Remote-Containers?

Comment: any luck with this? i'm having the same issue

Comment: @dirkenstocks I've added an answer pointing to the steps that I used to get around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just following up because it's been some time since I solved this, but (if memory serves me well) the problem was that my host wasn't set up to do agent forwarding - it was nothing to do with the devcontainer.

I used [these comprehensive instructions to set up agent forwarding and check its functionality](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/25/what-is-ssh-agent-forwarding-and-how-do-you-use-it/).